# Write and Read - Socket AF_UNIX

Tags: c, sockets

i'm doing a project for University. Need to write the code of a socket and one server and one client that talk trought this socket. Messagges are like:

```
typedef struct {
  /** message type */
    char type;           
  /** message length in byte */
    unsigned int length; 
  /** message buffer */
    char *buffer;        
  } message_t;
```

I wrote code of Socket and now i'm having problems with two function :sendMessage and receiveMessage

```
    /** read a message from the socket --- properly split the message and put it in the struct message_t 
 *  \param  sc  file descriptor of the socket
 *  \param msg  
 *
 *  \retval lung  length of the buffer read, if it's OK 
 *  \retval  -1   if there are errors (set errno)
 *                
 *      
 */
int receiveMessage(int sc, message_t * msg) {

  int lung;

  lung = read(sc, &(msg->type), sizeof(char));
  if(lung == 0) 
    return -1;
  if(lung == -1)
    return -1;

  lung = read(sc, &(msg->length), sizeof(unsigned int));
  if(lung == 0)
    return -1;
  if(lung == -1)
    return -1;

  if(msg->length > 0) {

    msg->buffer = malloc (sizeof(char)*msg->length);

    lung = read(sc, &(msg->buffer), sizeof(char)*msg->length);
    if(lung == 0)
      return -1;
    if(lung == -1)
      return -1;
  }
  return lung;
   }
```

This is sendMessage

```
/** write a message on the socket --- should send only significant byte of the buffer    (msg->length byte) --  must use only 1 write
 *   \param  sc file descriptor of the socket
 *   \param msg address of the struct 
 *   
 *   \retval  n    no. of char sent (if its OK)
 *   \retval -1   if there are errores (set errno)
 *                  
 *                  
 */
int sendMessage(int sc, message_t *msg) {

  int n,lung;

  lung = sizeof(unsigned int) + sizeof(char) + (sizeof(char)*msg->length);

  record = malloc (lung);

  sprintf(record,"%c%u%s",msg->type,msg->length,msg->buffer);

  n = write(sc,record,lung);
  if(n == 0) 
    return -1;
  return n;

}
```

Test return INVALID ARGUMENT of the receiveMessage and no message are write and read in the socket, i think the problem is with length of buffer (an unsigned int)
Any advice?

Comment: `sprintf` formats human-readable strings, not data into a binary buffer. Thus, one thing I see wrong immediately is that your buffer is too small because `msg->length` may be larger than `sizeof(unsigned int)`.

Comment: `memcpy` will copy bytes, but keep in mind that the size and endianness of an `unsigned int` might vary across platforms. You could deal with the size by using the sized types from `stdint.h` and you can deal with the endianness with functions such as `htonl`.

Comment: @DarkFalcon AF_UNIX sockets are local on the machine, there'll be no endian concerns.

Comment: @nos Right, sorry, I did not notice this was `AF_UNIX` sockets. There will be endian issues with sockets which communicate with other machines, such as `AF_INET`.

Answer (score 2):

Check the manpage for read on what it says about EINVAL, you're either sending in an invalid socket, or an invalid pointer to read(). Try to debug which of your read() call that fails too.

However this is wrong:

```
lung = read(sc, &(msg->buffer), sizeof(char)*msg->length);
```

Your buffer is a pointer, and you want to read the data wherever that points, not to its address. So it should be

```
lung = read(sc, msg->buffer, sizeof(char)*msg->length);
```